# Second Ajax request doesn't work after the first one is successful in jQuery mobile/Phonegap

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to jQuery Mobile & Phonegap. I am trying to build an app that can run on multiple platforms. Basically, I have one HTML file that has some DIVs inside (used as different pages). From the home screen, I have a button to link to another page like this:

```
<a href="#getCategories" onclick='GetCategories(0);' data-transition="pop"
  data-role="button">Get Categories</a>.
```

`GetCategories(categoryid)` has the Ajax request to return results based on the variable categoryid.

I can get to the "#getCategories" screen and all info is shown properly without any problems. I have about 6 categories and each of them has a different categoryid, from 1 to 6. I also make a link `GetCategories(categoryid)` in each category to retrieve their sub-categories, but it doesn't work.

Please note that in the DIV that I use to fill in all information returned from the web service, I set the id for it (of course it doesn't work). If I use the 'class'  of this div, it will work but the back button will point straight to the home page, not to the parent category.

I really want it so that each page can navigate back to the right one, i.e. the page that has subcategories will lead to their parent category page if the back button is clicked.

Any suggestion will be really appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: you need to put some more code which we can check

Comment: where's the code for the ajax request?

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
$('#your_a_id').bind('vclick', function(){ GetCategories(0); });
```

Attributes Javascript events  usually doesn't run on HTML with jquery mobile.

Use always .bind() and jqmobile events. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html